# How to wield update-alternatives properly?

Tags: ubuntu, alternatives

I was just trying to install `vanilla-gnome-desktop` by means of

```
apt install vanilla-gnome-desktop
```

... in order to get a more vanilla GNOME experience than the default on Ubuntu Desktop 18.04.

It errored out the first time around and the problem doesn't appear to be fixable by a mere `apt install` either:

```
# apt install vanilla-gnome-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
vanilla-gnome-desktop is already the newest version (0.83).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up plymouth-theme-ubuntu-gnome-logo (18.04.0) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative link /usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.grub is already managed by default.grub
dpkg: error processing package plymouth-theme-ubuntu-gnome-logo (--configure):
 installed plymouth-theme-ubuntu-gnome-logo package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 plymouth-theme-ubuntu-gnome-logo
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So anyway, I had previously purged the packages `plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo` and `plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text` and *installed* `plymouth-disabler`.

I furthermore created myself a little file `/etc/grub-black-and-white` containing:

```
if background_color 0,0,0,0; then
    clear
fi
```

Which I "installed" by means of

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.grub default.grub /etc/grub-black-and-white 100
```

However, I had to remove that (`update-alternatives --remove default.grub /etc/grub-black-and-white`) in order for `plymouth-theme-ubuntu-gnome-logo` to be installed properly, fixing the above issue.

But now when I want to reinstantiate my fixed `/usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.grub`, pointing to `/etc/grub-black-and-white`, it complains again:

```
# update-alternatives --install /usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.grub default.grub /etc/grub-black-and-white 100
update-alternatives: error: alternative link /usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.grub is already managed by default.plymouth
```

While I obviously can once again manually override it, my goal would be to have my setting take precedence over whatever some package chooses for `/usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.grub` and for that to *persist*.

Is there a way to achieve this with `update-alternatives`? How?